# Is there a LINQ equivalent to SQL's "0 rows affected"?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have a simple LINQ to SQL delete statement and would like to know if there is a way to find out the number of records deleted?

Sample code would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you out:
[GetChangeSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx)

Comment: That helps but doesn't solve my problem. If I try to delete a record that doesn't exist, the LINQ statement throws an exception and the GetChangeSet call never happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mcass20 - Just because LINQ throws an exception in this case, doesn't mean the entire Submit gets rolled back. It will depend on what you do with the exception.